# Product of Coprime Numbers Equals A Third Power (Number Theory)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, coprime

I understand that if two coprime integers a and b are such that $ab=x^2$,  then a and b must also be perfect squares.

Are there any similar properties if $ab=y^3$?

Comment: Yes, again assuming they are relatively prime.

Comment: Based off the title I’m assuming that in both propositions $a$ and $b$ are coprime. If that is the case, this also applies to $ab = x^3$ and generalized to arbitrary powers.

Comment: You can find many other related questions via the "linked" question on the linked dupes.